# Magento 1.9.2 : Unable to save data in custom model

Tags: magento-1.9

Namespace : Cart/ Save

My Config.xml are belows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cart_Save>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Cart_Save>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <save>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Cart_Save</module>
                    <frontName>save</frontName>
                </args>
            </save>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <save>
                    <file>save.xml</file>
                </save>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <save>
                <class>Cart_Save_Model</class> <!-- Location of all model class files -->
                <resourceModel>save_mysql4</resourceModel> <!-- Location of resource model -->
            </save>
            <save_mysql4>
                <class>Cart_Save_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <save>
                        <table>customers_save_cart</table> <!-- Actual table name in sql -->
                    </save>
                </entities>
            </save_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources> <!-- These are resource setting giving access to module, read/write permission on database -->
            <save_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Cart_Save</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </save_setup>
            <save_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </save_write>
            <save_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </save_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
             <save>
                <class>Cart_Save_Block</class>
            </save>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <save>
                <class>Cart_Save_Helper</class>
            </save>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Model for SQL4

```
class Cart_Save_Model_Mysql4_Save extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract{
    protected function _contruct() {
        $this->_init('save/save','id');   
    }
}
```

Model

```
class Cart_Save_Model_Save extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {
    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('save/save');  
    }
}
```

Trying to save Data in Cart Controller which i had overwrite

```
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
class View_Cart_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    public function getAllCartValuesAction()
    {
        if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):
            $quote = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote();
            $value = [];
            $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
            foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
                $value[]= array (
                                'id'=>1,
                                'customers_id' => (int) $customerId,
                                'sku' => $item->getSku(),
                                'quantity' => $item->getQty(),
                                'name' => $item->getName(),
                            );
            }
            $getSaveModel = Mage::getModel('save/save')->setData($value[0])->save();
            /*$getSaveModel->setData($value[0]);
            $getSaveModel->save();*/
            // print_r($value);die;
        endif; 
    }
}
```

While trying to execute save method faces below error

```
Fatal error: Class Cart_Save_Model_Mysql4_Save contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract::_construct) in D:\Projects\xampp\htdocs\m1-1\app\code\local\Cart\Save\Model\Mysql4\Save.php on line 2
```

Can Any one help me in this

Comment: Can you please show your table structure?

Comment: For table structure 
http://prntscr.com/kxy5ti/direct

Comment: Where you define resource model?You need also define  resource model.

Comment: Have mentioned in config.xml
<resourceModel>save_mysql4</resourceModel>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo in file Cart_Save_Model_Mysql4_Save: `_contruct()` should be changed to `_construct()`

Comment: Have changed the typo still not able to insert data in db

Comment: What's the error you got after changing the typo?

Comment: No error but not able to insert data in Database

Comment: Try to clear your cache and try again. Sometimes it helps.

And by the way, if column `id` in your table is autoincrement, then you should not include it into array.